After swapping stack in program on linux I cannot make function calls from externam files anymore
I am experimenting with the concept of swapping the stack to custom allocated memory in C (for changing the stack pointer and preserving registers, I am obviously using assembly). It is experiment on Linux x86_64.
Swapping is quite easy and works fine. I can call all functions from my files with no problems, and everything runs smoothly. Essentially, when the program starts, I push all registers to the stack, and then write the new stack pointer to the rsp register.
My stack after swapping looks somewhat like this, depending on what functions I call:
#2  0x0000555555555634 in unblock_signals () at stack_swap.c:53
#3  0x00005555555552ed in test1 () at kernel.c:36
#4  0x0000000000100000 in ?? ()
#5  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()

However, after I change my stack, any function call from files outside the compiled one ends up with a Segmentation Fault. GDB reports that the problem is that after changing stack I cannot find system files responsible for those operations: like printf, or changing signal masks.
For example:
43  ./nptl/pthread_sigmask.c: No such file or directory.

I wonder why this happens. If program running main stack can access them, then what should I do to preserve that after changing stack pointer.
I was thinking to try unwind the original stack and copy everything from there to the new stack? But I am not sure if that is correct approach as I will have to populate with same information few different stacks.
What I am aiming to do is achieve a somewhat RTOS-like behavior—running a timer in the background and swapping between different tasks with different stacks. This is purely an educational experiment.
Hence, I would like to have few tasks running and freely executing function calls, and have posix timer in background calling function for changing between tasks (swapping their stacks).

That is not the error. That's just gdb trying to show you the source code but you don't have it installed. The likely cause is that you misaligned the stack. Use x/i $pc to see the faulting instruction. It is likely going to be an SSE instruction that requires alignment. PS: printf and friends are not system calls.

Related: glibc scanf Segmentation faults when called from a function that doesn't align RSP

You should be using sigaltstack and a signal to set a new stack in a POSIX defined way. There is also (sig)setjmp and (sig)longjmp that you can use for switching stacks. No need to mess with assembly. But if you do beware of the RED ZONE. As Jester mentioned SSE needs stack alignment. This includes any varargs usage like printf.

Well, point of experiment is to use assembly - that is part of fun :)
